# MSAccess: ReadOnly Link to an External Data Source (Salesforce Account Table)?

Tags: ms-access

I am able to link to our Salesforce Accounts table from MSAccess (via my Admin User login).  This provides me the welcome benefit not needing to manually "Export" using SFDC Data Loader functionality to perform data maintenance and synchronization tasks w/3rd party data.

This approach gives me strong reservations as this link is Read/Write to live data.  I am currently the only user to see this AccessDB/table and perform these maintenance tasks, but still does not preclude me from inadvertently doing something really STUPID.

Here's my current thought (short of a formal ReadOnly method):

1. Retain the LINKED SFDC table in my local AccessDB, but HIDE in MSAccess' Navigator
2. OnOpen (or some other event) - COPY the full contents of the linked table into a LOCAL Table
3. Perform necessary queries & maintenance tasks referencing the LOCAL table only

Is there a better way to accomplish this task?  Maybe Link>Copy>Unlink>Maintain afresh for each new session?

Comment: Eh... Just create a login that only has read access? If you link tables, you usually provide the login (including password) with the table (it does require some expertise to get this back) but generally you should have a separate login for linked tables that users are allowed to know. Or prompt users for their login.

Comment: Can you retrieve the Salesforce table data with a [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/303968/how-to-create-an-sql-pass-through-query-in-access)?  If so, you could get rid of the linked table and pass-through queries are always read-only.

Comment: Got it!  I was able to construct an ODBC Connect string that worked, even though there was no pre-existing ODBC DSN named "Salesforce".  As follow: 
 "ODBC;Driver={Salesforce};uid=<<my uid>>;;Table=<<my table>>".  The resulting Passthrough query is ReadOnly!

Comment: Ugh, and now it's not working.  When I attempt to open the Passthrough query, I see a login dialog for "Amazon Redshift" - we are not a client of theirs.  My testing yesterday survived a few intentional reboots.  No such luck today.  I thought I was on a great path.  More tinkering.

Comment: I notice if I re-LINK to the remote SFDC table, the passthru query is working again.  I guess MSAccess provides the ODBC connectivity/driver. I do see other vendors selling SFDC ODBC Drivers.  Hope this approach will survive long term.